# List out only the file name from folder using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I have to List all the files inside a folder, and save the files according to their name in different folders, using spark. I have written below code but getting error

> split is not a member of org.hadoop, while using operator split.

Below is my code can anyone suggest me how to remove or overcome this error.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col 
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf 
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object Three extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder
                 .master("local[*]")
                 .appName("ListFile")
                 .getOrCreate()

  val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  import spark.implicits._

  import  org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem,Path}

  val files = FileSystem
                  .get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
                  .listStatus(new 
                  Path("C:\\Users\\ayush.gupta\\Desktop\\Newfolder25"))

 for(x<-files){
     val z= x.getPath
     println(z)

     val k = List(z)

    val word = k.map(a=> 
         a.split("""\/""")).last.map(y=>y.split("""\."""))

  val ay = word.last

  val ak = ay(0)

  val an = List(ak)

  val ni = an.map{
    s=>
        val m =  s.split("-")
        val jk = m(0)
        jk
  }

 val l = ni.map(ar=>ar.length).sum
 if (l == 2)
     df.saveAsTextFile("C:\\Users\\ayush.gupta\\Desktop\\a36.txt")    
 else
    df.saveAsTextFile("C:\\Users\\ayush.gupta\\Desktop\\a37.txt")
}
```

Comment: formatting hint on Stack Overflow - select code and type Ctrl+K to auto-format it

Comment: What exactly are you trying to split? Why are you using Spark and Hadoop FileSystem API at all if it's all local? I think you can fix your error just using plain Scala

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Scala, below is one way to move files from one folder to the other folders based on the file names.

```
import java.io.File
import java.util.regex.Pattern

import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.{ Files, Path, StandardCopyOption }

object SegregateFilesToFolders {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val path = "C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\All\\Data\\ExcelFilesComparison\\files"
        val files = new File(path).list.toList // gives list of file names including extensions in the path `path`

        println(files)

        val out_path = "C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\"  // In Desktop, I have created folders which match expected file names

        for (f <- files) {
            val p = Pattern.compile("(.+?)(\\.[^.]*$|$)") // regex to identify files names and extensions
            val m = p.matcher(f)

            if (m.find()) {
                val d1 = new File(path + s"\\$f").toPath
                val d2 = new File(out_path + s"${m.group(1)}" + s"\\$f").toPath // m.group(1) gives the file name without extension ... $f gives the file name with extension

                Files.move(d1, d2, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I used the below path  val path = "C:\\Users\\ayush.gupta\\Desktop\\Newfolder25\\"
  val out_path = "C:\\Users\\ayush.gupta\\Desktop\\Newfolder25\\2"   but getting  java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\ayush.gupta\Desktop\Newfolder25 -> C:\Users\ayush.gupta\Desktop\Newfolder25\2: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. I checked evrythng but not getting the error , the file is not being used by any processor, can you help here?

Comment: In hope you are using folder name `2` in the output path to move file named `2.*`. If that is your case, keep output path till `C:\\Users\\ayush.gupta\\Desktop\\Newfolder25` . In my code I am adding `2` dynamically to the output path.

Comment: Hi Praveen, I have created an empty folder with a name "2" and trying to move the file from C:\Users\ayush.gupta\Desktop\Newfolder25 to C:\Users\ayush.gupta\Desktop\Newfolder25\2 but getting the above error. Can u help to figure out wats the problm?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `split`, you can use getName method which returns the file name.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
val path = ??? // your path
val files = FileSystem.get(conf).listStatus(new Path(path))
val fileNames: Array[String] = files.map(_.getPath.getName)
```

You can also use `filter` method with a predicate on the file name.

```
val filteredFiles = files.filter(_.getPath.getName.length == ???)
```